# Como agregar un spinner a mi aplicacion mientras navego entre paginas c# Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

estoy trabajando en un proyecto con blazor y quería saber como agregar un spinner mientras se navega entre cuestionarios ya que de momento solo me sale un Loading... el problema es que al agregarlo como lo he hecho en el resto del proyecto toda la pagina comienza a girar, actualmente el Loading... esta así:

```
<div id="app">Loading...</div>

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
```

Dentro de un body pero bueno es medio largo como para agregarlo todo

Comment: pues.. cambia ese loading por lo que queres que salga.. cual seria el problema???

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: El problema es que cuando lo agrego todo el formulario comienza a girar..

Comment: y como podriamos saber que pasa, si no vemos que intentaste? estas usando alguna libreria por ejemplo? como lo agregaste?